# Issue with Shiny Server, Brackets aren't happy with me

Tags: r, shiny

My Server was running just fine until I made some changes to the ui. R is not happy with the way I am using my brackets. See Below for full code.

```
library(leaflet)
library(RgoogleMaps)
leaflet(ImpactPOS) %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
  setView( -116.55, 35.25, 10) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~lng, ~lat, radius = 1, color = "red")


library(shiny)


r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"), 
  p(),
  actionButton("Date", "BLUFOR"),
  
  sliderInput("integer", "Integer:",
              min = 3, max = 18,
              value = 10),
  tableOutput("values")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  read.csv("C:\Users\Jim Downey\Desktop\School\Spring 2021\SE402\Files for John")
  
  
  
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(ImpactPOS) %>%
      addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
      setView( -116.55, 35.25, 10) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(~lng, ~lat, radius = 1, color = "red") %>% 
    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run this everything runs great until I try to run the server and I get this error back.

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: Remove the `%>%` at the end of `addCircleMarkers(~lng, ~lat, radius = 1, color = "red") %>% `

Comment: also, in your `read.csv` the backslash is used as an escape character...if you want to use them in a string, try using double backslash \\ to escape the backslash...